# Qt button animation changes text color

Tags: c++, qt, animation

I have button set up like this:

```
button->setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(194, 194, 194);"
                      "color: rgb(0, 0, 0);"
                      "font: bold 20px;"
                      "border-radius: 30px");
```

When I hover over the button, I want to make it fluently change color. I already redefined function eventFilter() of the main window, to catch this event.

```
if (object == (QObject*) button)
    {
        if (event->type() == QEvent::Enter)
            animate(button,  QColor(194, 194, 194), QColor(235, 235, 235));
        
        else if (event->type() == QEvent::Leave)
            animate(button, QColor(235, 235, 235), QColor(194, 194, 194));

        return QWidget::eventFilter(object, event);
    }
```

Function animate should make simple fluent change of background, but it also changes text color, which I cannot change after (even using button->styleSheet()). Function animate looks like this:

```
effect = new QGraphicsColorizeEffect(button);
animation = new QPropertyAnimation(effect, "color");

button->setGraphicsEffect(effect);

animation->setStartValue(start_val);
animation->setEndValue(end_val);
animation->setDuration(250);
animation->start();
```

I have buttons with white text too, but I don't have the same problem with them. What's wrong? What could be improved to get rid of this 'error'?

Comment: `QGraphicsColorizeEffect` affects the whole button, not just the background. Make a custom button with a color property and reimplement the paint event.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add a hover transition to QPushButton?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53084981/how-to-add-a-hover-transition-to-qpushbutton)